# Maximum zoom scale on UIButton images?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I'm using a pinch gesture recognizer to handle zooming a button that has an image. I established the image using

```
[self.button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

In my pinch gesture recognizer handler, I'm scaling the button by altering its frame.size:

```
self.button.frame = [self makeButtonFrame];
```

where makeButtonFrame uses the current scale (adjusted by the pinch gesture recognizer handler):

```
- (CGRect) makeButtonFrame {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake (STROKE_WIDTH + DISTANCE_FROM_STROKE, 
                               STROKE_WIDTH + DISTANCE_FROM_STROKE, 
                               self.scale * self.defaultWidth, 
                               self.scale * self.defaultHeight);
    return frame;
}
```

I find that I cannot scale the button image beyond a certain point with this technique. And that scale seems to vary dependent on the specific image (double ugh!). That scale seems to be around 3-4.

Currently I'm conservatively limiting the scale to a factor of 3 in my pinch gesture recognizer.

However, I'd like a more analytic means of determining a maximum scale. Instead of just estimating based on a set of images I've tried.

Comment: Does 'cannot scale the button image beyond a certain point' mean that scaling it too much makes button image look bad, or ??? You could look at the `image.size` and set the maximum scale based on that (i.e., don't scale the button beyond the size of the image).

Comment: I mean, changing the frame of the button to increase its size has no effect. It remains at it's previous size. I'll look at the image.size. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say for certain, but I suspect that this 'limit' is actually your image's size. When you set a button's `image` (as opposed to `backgroundImage`), your image will be scaled down if it's larger than the frame. If the image is smaller, then it's simply centered in the frame (the frame still governs what area responds to touches, though). I think what you're seeing is your image scaled down when you place it in the button, and it scales up until it reaches it's original size, at which point it scales no further. There are two solutions to this:

1: Use the `backgroundImage` instead of the image property:

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The background image always expands to fill the frame, no matter how big it is or how much it distorts the image.

2: Use the `transform` property to scale. This is done like so:

```
self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleAmountX, scaleAmountY);
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to adjust your frame at all - not even for the position offset, as scaling using the transform matrix does so from the center rather than from a corner. It should also respond to touches within it's scaled-up area.

Comment: Yes, the "limit" was the actual size of image. I just checked this out. I used your backgroundImage method suggestion, and it works like a charm. Thanks for the ideas!!